# CSS: 3 Columns Layout with Fixed Sidebar Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want to achieve 3 column layouts with the sidebar navigation being fixed but

```
position:fixed
```

doesn't play well on **float** property

This is what I have now:

```
<div id="container">
  <sidebar>
      <!-- MENU -->
  </sidebar>

  <div class="middle-panel">
    <!-- MIDDLE STUFF LIKE SEARCH BUTTON -->
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
     <!-- MAIN STUFF COMES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

#container
{
  height: 100%; 
}

sidebar
{
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.middle-panel
{
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content
{
  height: 100%
}
```

1) Currently if I don't remove **position:fixed** then the middle panel float won't be applied but I want a fixed sidebar. Any suggestions ?
2) Also I think of using **bootstrap** to make it responsive. How would this work with this layout.

This is how the layout should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you apply "position: fixed" to an element, it is taken out of the flow of the document, meaning anything else in the document will collapse under/on top of the fixed element.  So essentially what is happening is your floated elements are falling on top of your fixed sidebar.  Here's what you need to do:

Either move the sidebar outside the container (since it is now out of the flow of the document now anyways):

```
<sidebar>
    <!-- MENU -->
</sidebar>

<div id="container">

  <div class="middle-panel">
    <!-- MIDDLE STUFF LIKE SEARCH BUTTON -->
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
     <!-- MAIN STUFF COMES HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Or wrap your other elements inside a new container:

```
<div id="container">

  <sidebar>
      <!-- MENU -->
  </sidebar>

  <div id="another_container">    
    <div class="middle-panel">
      <!-- MIDDLE STUFF LIKE SEARCH BUTTON -->
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <!-- MAIN STUFF COMES HERE -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Then give either your #container (my first example), or your new #another_container (my second example) a margin-left of however wide you want your sidebar to be.  In your example it's 350px.  You'll never make a fixed element responsive the way you want to use it, so setting this fixed margin won't be a problem.  You can make the rest of the elements responsive instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put the sidebar and the middle panel in a parent div that has a fixed position.

```
<div class="sidebar-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Side panel 1
  </div>
  <div class="middle-panel">
    Middle Panel
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    Main Content - Scrollable
</div>

<style>
    .sidebar-container {
         position: fixed;
         left: 0;
     }
    .sidebar, .middle-panel {
         display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: yeah almost but in the middle panel now the width is not pushing the main-content :/

Comment: Add a margin-left: __px; to the main-content div